# [Custom Directive]Difference between putting scope.$watch on link vs scope.$watch on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry if this has been answered but I can't find a documentation that satisfy myself.

What's the difference between using the scope.$watch on the link vs the controller function in the custom directive?

```
var linker = function (scope, element) {

    // same watch block
    scope.$watch('propertyToWatch', function (value) {

    });

    element.html(template).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};

return {
    require: '^directiveName',
    scope: {

    },
    link: linker,
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        // same watch block
        scope.$watch('propertyToWatch', function (value) {
        });
    }
```

My application behaves exactly the same putting logic in both places. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, other than it being in a different place.

Comment: I thought there might be something related to the $scope.$digest or $scope.$apply

Comment: Nope, has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally there is no difference between the two - either way you're adding a watcher to the scope (if it acted differently then there would be a problem!).

I tend to add watchers in the directive to control how external attributes are mapped to internal scope variables (similar to the directive isolate scope). i.e. the controller doesn't care where the values come from, as long as they are on the scope.

I then use watchers in the controller to watch values on those internal properties - to know when sub-properties have changed and respond to that inside the controller. i.e. the directive doesn't care about how the properties are used, it just needs to put them on the scope for the controller.

Here is an example using isolate scope:

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            // The isolate scope sets up a watcher on the external
            // property and makes it available on the scope
            // as `scope.internalProp`
            'internalProp': '=externalProp'
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            // Work with `internalProp` - the directive
            // manages putting it on the scope.
            $scope.internalProp //...

            $scope.$watch('internalProp.myProp', function(value){
                // Do something when `myProp` changes.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is an example using a child scope but mapping the same external value to `scope.internalProp`.
This doesn't create an isolate scope so you still get scope inheritance (which can be useful sometimes).

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myDirective', function($parse){
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            // Example of manually watching an attribute value
            // in a directive.

            var propGetter = $parse(attr['externalProp']);
            scope.$parent.$watch(propGetter, function(value){
                scope.internalProp = value;
            });
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            // Work with `internalProp` - the directive
            // manages putting it on the scope.
            $scope.internalProp //...

            $scope.$watch('internalProp.myProp', function(value){
                // Do something when `myProp` changes.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In both examples it's the directive that controls how external attributes are mapped to internal scope properties and then the controller can work with those internal properties as-needed.